# Баланс скобок в выражении

Tags: php, brackets

> Написать функцию, которая на входе принимает строку из скобок, и возвращает true если все открытые скобки закрыты, иначе - false. Возможные варианты скобок: ()[]{}.
>
> Пример:
>
> "(){}[]" => true
>
> "([{}])" => true
>
> "(}" => false
>
> "[(])" => false
>
> "[({})](]" => false

Мною было предложено следующее решение:

```
<?php

function isBracketsBalanced (string $input) : bool {

  $costs = [
    '[' =>  1, '(' =>  10, '{' =>  100,
    ']' => -1, ')' => -10, '}' => -100
  ];
  $brackets = str_split ($input);
  $opened = [- $costs [end ($brackets)]];
  $balance = 0;

  while (($bracket = array_pop ($brackets)) !== NULL) {

    $cost = $costs [$bracket];
    $balance += $cost;

    if ($cost < 0)
    
      $opened [] = - $cost;
      
    else if ($cost == end ($opened))
    
      array_pop ($opened);

    else
    
      return FALSE;
  }

  return $balance == 0;
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/SandyPriceyDevices

Резюме проверяющего: задача решена на хорошем, но недостаточно высоком уровне.

Может кто-нибудь объяснить что именно в предложенном мной решении на "недостаточно высоком уровне"?

Comment: А почему вы у него не спросите?

Comment: а если сразу открыты и закрыты

Comment: С проверявшим я напрямую не общался, а затевать дискуссию через кадровика, да еще по почте то еще удовольствие.

Comment: что-то не совсем понятно. что получится если будет 10 скобок `[` и одна `)`, и почем нельзя было просто подсчитать число закрывающих и открывающих.

Comment: получится false

Comment: @leninel почему у вас код не по PSR стандартам оформления?
и где тесты?

Comment: Скобки фигурные по коду расставить всё-таки надо, особенно в if-else...

Comment: читайте условия задачи

Comment: стиль кодирования определяет высоту уровня?

Comment: @leninel прочитал не понимаю как это соотносится с моим вопросом

Comment: @Eugene Nagornichyh я тоже не понимаю каким боком ваш комментарий относится к моему вопросу.

Comment: @leninel ваш алгоритм можно сделать проще, я так бы решал
1. Определил тип скобки 2. Посчитал кол-во открывающихся закрывающихся

Comment: @Eugene Nagornichyh не сочтите за труд привести свое решение

Comment: @leninel ниже уже ответили

Comment: если ваш код работает корректно, то ответ будет основан на чисто субъективном подходе (по правилам такой вопрос следует закрыть) Меня вот напрягает форматирование кода. В целом смотря на код, алгоритм не становится очевидным и понятным. Вы не хотите в качестве ответа другое решение, но если другое решение будет проще и понятнее, то это и есть показатель "достаточно высокого уровня". можно написать сортировку пузырьком за квадрат, а можно быструю. И если у вас решение за квадрат, то вы попадете в категорию "недостаточно высокого уровня". Но и о простоте и красоте кода забывать не надо

Comment: в общем говоря, задайтесь вопросом, можно ли решить эту задачу проще и понятнее. Если можно, то ответ, очевиден. Да и в целом задача весьма популярная,  так что существует так сказать классическое ее решение, это оно?

Comment: @teran, мой код работает корректно (доказательство сего факта элементарно).  я не знаю насколько оно классическое. если вы можете привести другое корректное решение с объяснением чем именно оно отличается от моего в лучшую сторону я буду вам очень признателен.

Answer (score 3):

Вот формально, зачем вообще у вас какой то баланс и эти значения  1,10,100 ?
Вам вроде нужен стек, открывающая скобка - добавляете в стек. Закрывающая - смотрите на вершине парная или нет. Если парная то удаляете, иначе вообще выход. Таков алгоритм должен быть? Если да, то при чем тут вообще эти числа?

```
function checkBraces($input){
    $braces = str_split($input);       
    $map = [']' => '[', ')' => '(', '}' => '{'];
    $closing = array_keys($map);

    $stack = [];

    foreach($braces as $b){
        if(!in_array($b, $closing)){
            $stack[] = $b;
            continue;
        }
        if(end($stack) != $map[$b]) return false;
        array_pop($stack);
    }
    return count($stack)  == 0;
}
```

еще можно вот так решить :D

```
function check2($input){
    $repl = str_replace(["}", ")", "]"],["{r", "(r", "[r"], $input);
    $result = preg_replace('/([\[({])(?R)*\1r/', "", $repl);

    return mb_strlen($result) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Это решение эквивалентно моему с точностью до обозначений. Оно не лучше моего ни по времени, ни по памяти. Потрудитесь объяснить где тут "высокий уровень"?

Comment: вы ответьте на вопросы, зачем вам `1,10,100`и арифметика с ними. это излишне и запутывает код. В том виде как он здесь написан решение предельно понятно. в вашем же не понятно. Если для вас нет разницы понятен код или нет, легко ли в нем разбираться и сопровождать, то у меня для вам плохие новости.

Comment: я ответил: эти решения эквивалентны. если вам в новинку такая методика, то и у меня для вас плохие новости. за сим считаю наш с вами диалог оконченным ибо не вижу перспектив.

Comment: @teran зачем два массива, выбросьте closing и сделайте `if(in_array($b, $map)){`

Comment: @splash58 тогда уж `isset($map[$b])` или `array_key_exists`. в целом да, два массива не нужны.

Comment: тока для isset перевернуть массив надо. будет клево :)

Comment: @teran, вот второе решение "достаточно высоко" и в 4 раза быстрее. снимаю шляпу.

Comment: @leninel несколько удивлен, что оно быстрее. Это в целом не алгоритмическое решение, обычно оно не представляет интереса в задачах такого типа.